# How can I display better HAML errors in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, better-errors-gem

for a long time now HAML syntax errors just spits out a generic error message, like this:

```
Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check .component.container-xl.my-3.no-p
    .component-header
        %div.float-end
```

I'm using the better_errors gem and if I scroll down to @cause, I can see the actual error here:

```
#<SyntaxError: /USER PATH STUFF ETC/index.html.haml:47: syntax error, unexpected '=' ...:Haml::Util.escape_html_safe((=number_to_human(investment.va... ... ^ >
```

Is there a way to display the @cause error on top? Maybe I'll fork the gem and customize the UI to accomplish this...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up forking and hacking better_errors to display the error I wanted here:
https://github.com/Swolie/drgn_better_errors